# What is the maximum URL length you can pass to the Wininet function, HttpOpenRequest?

Tags: url, wininet

What is the maximum URL length you can pass to the Wininet function, HttpOpenRequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpOpenRequest does not have a maximum length but server software you are targeting will likely have a limit on your URL length.

> **Apache (Server)**
>
> My early attempts to measure the
>   maximum URL length in web browsers
>   bumped into a server URL length limit
>   of approximately 4,000 characters,
>   after which Apache produces a "413
>   Entity Too Large" error. I used the
>   current up to date Apache build found
>   in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4. The
>   official Apache documentation only
>   mentions an 8,192-byte limit on an
>   individual field in a request.
>
> **Microsoft Internet Information Server (Server)**
>
> The default limit is 16,384 characters
>   (yes, Microsoft's web server accepts
>   longer URLs than Microsoft's web
>   browser). This is configurable.
>
> **Perl HTTP::Daemon (Server)**
>
> Up to 8,000 bytes will work. Those
>   constructing web application servers
>   with Perl's HTTP::Daemon module will
>   encounter a 16,384 byte limit on the
>   combined size of all HTTP request
>   headers. This does not include
>   POST-method form data, file uploads,
>   etc., but it does include the URL. In
>   practice this resulted in a 413 error
>   when a URL was significantly longer
>   than 8,000 characters. This limitation
>   can be easily removed. Look for all
>   occurrences of 16x1024 in Daemon.pm
>   and replace them with a larger value.
>   Of course, this does increase your
>   exposure to denial of service attacks.

(from [Boutell.com](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html))

Comment: Do you know if these limits include name value pairs (e.g. url?data=x..) or just the url itself?

Comment: @David Sykes: I *believe* the limits are based the size of the buffer used to store the characters so I would assume that includes name-value pairs. But I'm just speculating.

Comment: *"HttpOpenRequest does not have a maximum length"* - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293129/1889329) disagress with that statement.

Answer (score 6):

There are some max length consts in WinInet.h:

```
...
//
// maximum field lengths (arbitrary)
//

#define INTERNET_MAX_HOST_NAME_LENGTH   256
#define INTERNET_MAX_USER_NAME_LENGTH   128
#define INTERNET_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH    128
#define INTERNET_MAX_PORT_NUMBER_LENGTH 5           // INTERNET_PORT is unsigned short
#define INTERNET_MAX_PORT_NUMBER_VALUE  65535       // maximum unsigned short value
#define INTERNET_MAX_PATH_LENGTH        2048
#define INTERNET_MAX_SCHEME_LENGTH      32          // longest protocol name length
#define INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH         (INTERNET_MAX_SCHEME_LENGTH \
                                        + sizeof("://") \
                                        + INTERNET_MAX_PATH_LENGTH)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

[I would suggest less than 2000 characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-url/417184#417184), but this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427/) suggests Internet Explorer has a limit of 2083, which may well apply to your case too.

Comment: Yes, we are failing around this amount