# URLDownloadToFile fails with 0x800c0008 (INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE) depending on length of URL

Tags: c++, winapi, urlmon

I'm aware there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441922/urldownloadtofile-fails-with-code-0x800c0008-inet-e-download-failure). However my symptoms differ. There seems to be some kind of URL length restriction in place that I couldn't find [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85)). The limit seens to be 2084 (sic! not 2048!) characters in the URL. The easiest repro is just a console application with this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "urlmon.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon")


int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL,L"http://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?oids=1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890",
        L"c:\\temp\\x.png",
        0,
        NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, the URL doesn't make actual sense, in my real life example these are important parameters. As soon as I shorten the URL below 2084 characters, I get back S_OK and everything is fine.

I used Fiddler to check the request which tells me I'm seeing http status code 200 (OK) for the download and even the server response is just perfect:

[image: server response]

Is there any way to download URLs longer than 2084 characters using URLDownloadToFile?

Comment: Do you have to use URLDownloadToFile?

Comment: In some cases you may be able to work around the URL length limitation by doing a POST instead of a GET request. For a POST request, the URL parameters can be send in the body of the request (application/x-www-form-urlencoded), which has a much bigger length limit. A POST request can't be done with `URLDownloadToFile` though, so you have to look for another API.

Comment: Voting to reopen as it's a similar yet subtly different effect and not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinInet's `INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH` constant is exactly 2084, including a null terminator.

Also see the answers to [What is the maximum URL length you can pass to the Wininet function, HttpOpenRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010121/) for various other URL-related limits.

If you need to download a longer URL, you will have to use another HTTP client library.

Comment: Ah, OK, I was looking at restrictions specific to urlmon. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Still it's strange to see that the download itself obviously just works fine while the API fails.